# How to created a dynamic list on Apex 4.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, plsql, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to create a Dynamic List on Oracle Apex 4.2 with an overlay of the twitter-bootstrap. I am trying to use the chat functionality, and in order to do that I would need to use an object list. I am trying to populate the list with and existing table, but the list does not populate. I was wondering if anyone can provide and example on how to create the dynamic lists.

Orcale provided this, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35125/nav_list.htm#HTMDB28677

```
SELECT level, labelValue label, 
       [targetValue]            target, 
       [is_current]             is_current_list_entry,
       [imageValue]             image, 
       [imageAttributeValue]    image_attribute,
       [imageAltValue]          image_alt_attribute,
       [attribute1]             attribute1,
       [attribute2]             attribute2,
       [attribute3]             attribute3,
       [attribute4]             attribute4,
       [attribute5]             attribute5,
       [attribute6]             attribute6,
       [attribute7]             attribute7,
       [attribute8]             attribute8,
       [attribute9]             attribute9,
       [attribute10]            attribute10
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

and I tried to put in this:

```
SELECT NULL, AUTHOR label, 
       '#'               target, 
       'test'            is_current_list_entry,
       ' '               image, 
       ' '               image_attribute,
       ' '               image_alt_attribute,
       RESPONSE          attribute1,
       DATE_CREATED      attribute2
FROM CHAT_RESPONSES
WHERE AUTHOR IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DATE_CREATED desc
```

The list did no populate and I was wondering if I am using this wrong.

Comment: It would be useful to share what you've tried. In this case, your query you've used to create a dynamic list with.

Comment: Are you referring to a List of values item? If so, a list of values requires only two fields max in the query definition one to display and one to return as value.

Comment: No, not a LoV. Just a regular List that can be updated dynamically. I am currently using a bootstrap application, and for some reason it cant use a table and requires a list to implement it.

Comment: Use 'Yes' , 'No' or NULL (not 'NULL') instead of 'test' in your dynamic List as is_current_list_entry in Query your select list  populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work,

```
    SELECT 1, e.First_Name||' '||e.Last_Name label,
      '#' target,
       NULL is_current_list_entry,  
      'http://orig03.deviantart.net/efa6/f/2015/200/5/6/anon_icon_thinger_by_arofexdracona-d920vda.png'   image,
       NULL image_attribute,
       NULL image_alt_attribute,
       'left' attribute1,
       'fa-clock-o' attribute2,
       DATE_CREATED attribute3,
       RESPONSE attribute4
    from RESPONSES r
    INNER JOIN PEOPLE e
    ON r.author = e.LANID
    where REQUESTID = v('P407_ID')
    order by DATE_CREATED DESC;
```

Now I'm currently trying to figure  a way to get that attribute 1 to alternate from left and right. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

in list of value creation there is a note as below in tooltips
so i think you should change 'test' to one of opetions below

NOTE:The is_current column can be set to one of the following three values:'YES','NO' or NULL. If set to NULL, the currency of the list entry will be based on the target page of the list entry.

Comment: I changed the null, but it seems the list is still not populating. Do you know if the table needs to be created in a certain way for it to be used to populate the list?

Comment: i made small test when it is 'NULL', it is not populated too but when i entered NULL or 'YES' or 'NO' it is populating so i use as one as one of the below 
'YES'            is_current_list_entry, or
'NO'            is_current_list_entry, or
NULL            is_current_list_entry,